# Yii Captcha not Changing

Tags: php, yii

My Captcha is not changing, always appear the same word, unless clicking on `Reload Captcha` button. Why `testLimit` is not working properly?

Controller.php

```
public $attempts = 5; // allowed 5 attempts
public $counter;

public function actions()
{
    return array(
        'captcha'=>array(
        'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
        'backColor'=>0xf5f5f5,
        'testLimit'=>1,
    );
}

private function captchaRequired()
{           
    return Yii::app()->session->itemAt('captchaRequired') >= $this->attempts;
}

public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) $this->redirect(array('users/update'));

    $model = $this->captchaRequired()? new LoginForm('captchaRequired') : new LoginForm;

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login()) {
            $this->redirect(array('users/update'));
        } else {
            $this->counter = Yii::app()->session->itemAt('captchaRequired') + 1;
            Yii::app()->session->add('captchaRequired',$this->counter);
        }
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

View.php

```
<?php if($model->scenario == 'captchaRequired'): ?>
    <br>
    <legend><?php echo CHtml::activeLabelEx($model,'verifyCode'); ?></legend>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
            <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`testLimit` is the amount of captcha submission, that user can try before generated hash will be changed. Used for avoid typo mistakes.

Verify code stores in session (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCaptchaAction#getVerifyCode-detail), thus be default code can be changed only one of two ways: submit form with `testLimit` times with incorrect code, or manual update by user.

So you can extends CCaptchaAction class to achieve what you want, f.g. force set `$regenerate` variable to true.

Answer (score 0):

Is simple solution, use JScript. This script will be reload image captha.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setTimeout(function () {
    $("img#reviews-verifycode-image").click();
}, 100);
});
```